# Issue in displaying Jenkins build data to influxDB

Tags: jenkins, influxdb

I am facing some issues in fetching Jenkins build data into influxDB. Actually, the main requirement is to show Jenkins job  build results on Grafana dashboard. So, I have created a Jenkins freestyle job and also installed influxDB plugin(1.17) and then I executed Windows batch command (as I am using a Windows 7 machine). it throws nullpointerexception. Please let me know what i need to do.
Images are given below.

configure InfluxDB details
[image]
Configure job
[image]
Build Configure Job
[image]
Build Outputlog
[image]

Comment: HI @spand. We need your log to try to help you. Also, is this a development environment?

Comment: yes.here is outputlog.  
D:\Jenkins\Slave\workspace\idws\POC\Influxdb-test>exit 0 
[InfluxDB Plugin] Publishing data to: [url=http://localhost:8086, description=influxdb, username=inluxdb, password=*****, database=influxdb]
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at jenkinsci.plugins.influxdb.InfluxDbPublisher.perform(InfluxDbPublisher.java:292)
 at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java.

Comment: I am not quite sure what your specific issue is, but here is that line in the jenkins plugin. It is throwing the null pointer when it is trying to use the Jenkins proxy to connect. If the DB is running locally do you need to use the proxy? If the jenkins global proxy is not configured then that could be causing the Null Pointer. https://github.com/jenkinsci/influxdb-plugin/blob/f765747acfe8df09ca9a62310391cad4c9ba382f/src/main/java/jenkinsci/plugins/influxdb/InfluxDbPublisher.java#L292

Comment: My DB is not running locally.it's running in another sever(win-APSET2359)which i used  as a  slave agent in jenkins and the job run on the same server.

Comment: Have you tried setting the host name of influx to be the hostname of win-APSET2359 :8086? Also is the global proxy defined inside Jenkins? Or does it work if you just uncheck the use proxy box

Comment: Could you use http://gist.github.com/ to share your log ?

Comment: if i uncheck the proxy box it shows connection failed error.   ERROR: Build step failed with exception
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
 Caused: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:8086

Comment: I already tried to change the hostname of win-APSET2359:8086 .it shows the same error NULLPOINTException.